# Trying to enable Tor Package repository on Ubuntu 22.04 - permission denied error when adding gpg key

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions, tor, keyrings

I'm trying to enable the Tor Package Repository on my Ubuntu 22.04 following these steps: https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/

Everything worked fine until step 3. When I run

```
wget -qO- https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
```

I get a permission denied error:

```
tee: /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg: Permission denied
```

My architecture is amd64, `lsb_release -c` gives `Codename: jammy` and `cat /etc/debian_version` gives `bookworm/sid`.
In step 2 I tried filling in both `jammy` and `bookworm/sid` for `<DISTRIBUTION>`, but with both I get the same error in step 3. I did not try any experimental packages, neither did I add the lines for focal, as I'm not running on focal.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to be root to write to system directories. So you need to prepend sudo to the tee command or run the whole thing as root
For example:

```
wget -qO- https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial you're working with assumes that your user has root privileges:

> Note: The symbol # refers to running the code as root. This means you should have access to a user account with system administration privileges, e.g your user should be in the sudo group.

On Ubuntu, you mostly work with "normal", unprivileged accounts, and get additional privileges with `sudo` in case you need them. One of the things you need additional privileges for is to write outside of your `$HOME` directory (meaning outside for example `/home/myusername/`).

This is exactly what the third part of the pipeline in question tries to do. `tee` tries to create a file in `/usr/share/keyrings/`, where your "normal" user account has no business murking around ;) So, you need to get privileged for this part by prefixing `sudo` to this part of the pipeline:

```
wget -qO- ... | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee ... >/dev/null
```

Note: The pipeline above is shortened to better illustrate the idea.

The first and second parts of the pipeline, `wget` and `pgp`, can work without additional privileges, so you don't need `sudo` there.